# ORACLE : How to take a count rows in a table inside a procedure while the table is being populated by another procedure (oracle job)

Tags: oracle, rowcount, dbms-job

I want to take count of a table inside a parent procedure while the table is being populated by another/child procedure. This second/chile procedure is started as a job from inside the first/parent.
The above is a simplistic description of certain decisions I need to take inside the first/parent based on the count. Example, If the row-count value of the table read inside the first/parent reaches a certain value I want to kill/remove the second/child job.
However, I am always getting the count(*) = 0 inside the first/parent, even though a select * on the table shows that the child procedure is populating the table.
What could be the reason and what is the way of getting a count ?
Below is a test script :

```
create table test_j(col1 number);

create or replace PROCEDURE parent_job_sp
as
    g_jobid_child   number := -1;
    v_child_cnt     number := -1;
begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('START - parent_job_sp');
    DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(g_jobid_child,'GFF_LOAD.child_job_sp;');
    COMMIT;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('g_jobid_child='||g_jobid_child);
    while (v_child_cnt<=8)
    loop
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('v_child_cnt='||v_child_cnt);
        execute immediate 'select count(*) from test_j' into v_child_cnt;
        if v_child_cnt >= 8
        then
            BEGIN 
                DBMS_JOB.remove(g_jobid_child); 
                COMMIT;
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('REMOVED JOB '||g_jobid_child);
            EXCEPTION 
                WHEN OTHERS THEN 
                    IF SQLCODE=-23421 
                    THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THEN'); 
                    ELSE DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ELSE'); 
                    END IF; 
            END;
        end if;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('OUTSIDE IF');
    end loop;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('OUTSIDE WHILE');
exception   --- proc-level exception
    when others then
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('parent_job_sp - '||SQLERRM);
end;    --- end proc

create or replace PROCEDURE child_job_sp
as
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
begin
    for cur_test in
    (
        select rownum row_num from dual connect by level<=1000
    )
    loop
        insert into test_j values (cur_test.row_num);
        commit;
    end loop;
    COMMIT;
exception   --- proc-level exception
    when others then
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('child_job_sp - '||SQLERRM);
end;    --- end proc
```

--- then run from SQL*Plus :  exec parent_job_sp

--- I always get v_child_cnt=0  even though the result of the select count(*) from test_j is 1000.

What could be the reason and what is the way of getting a count ?

Comment: first guess is your procedure isn't committing as it goes, so the other procedure comes in to count the rows, and it's in another session, so it can't see your uncommitted transaction

Comment: I dont think so. While running the above code, I let it run for quite some time and the value was v_child_cnt=0 always. Whereas, when I checked the count from another sql plus window, its showing 1000, even though the screen dump (dbms output) on the first window (running "exec parent_job_sp") was still "v_child_cnt=0"

Comment: Do you change your session's transaction isolation level before calling the parent procedure, perhaps?

Comment: Is there a chance the primary proc and the secondary job are resolving to tables under different schemas?